# How to find the range intervals of column with count & compare its values?

Tags: python, pandas

Below is my demo dataframe:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"a": np.random.randint(1, high=50, size=50)})
bins =np.arange(0,df['a'].max()+1,5).astype('int') # this range interval with 5
```

when i run below func i get range and its count like this.

```
df.a.value_counts(bins=bins,sort=False)

(-0.001, 5.0]     3
(5.0, 10.0]       2
(10.0, 15.0]      5
(15.0, 20.0]      3
(20.0, 25.0]      5
(25.0, 30.0]     10
(30.0, 35.0]      6
(35.0, 40.0]      6
(40.0, 45.0]      4
```

what i want is when i will give range say `[20:50]` it will return the maximum count between it .

Here it is `10` also i want to know it is within `[25:30]`. Also if possible real values between it or mean of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `overlaps` method:

```
# the counts
counts = df.a.value_counts(bins=bins,sort=False)

# query interval
interval = pd.Interval(20,50)

counts.loc[counts.index.overlaps(interval)].idxmax()
```

Comment: what to put in `interval`

Comment: @SurajS see updated answer. Sorry I forgot to include that.

Comment: but how to get mean or all values of this. `Interval(25.0, 30.0, closed='right')`

Comment: i want the average of either average of `((25+30)/2)` or all the values present in that `interval [25:30]`